# Python Curses: Exiting a program fast

Tags: python, ncurses, python-curses

What is the best way to quickly exit a Python program with an infinite loop that uses curses module?

I've tried adding nodelay() method coupled with this at the end of the loop:

```
if screen.getch() == ord('q'):
    break
```

However, it takes 2-3 seconds to make all the function calls on one iteration of the loop. And because of the application, it doesn't make sense to run the loop more often than every 5 second. This means that in order for my way of exiting the program to work, I sometimes have to press and hold 'q' for 2-8 seconds.

My code looks like this:

```
import curses
import time

def main(screen):
    refresh_rate = 5
    screen.nodelay(1)

    # Infinite loop. Displays information and updates it 
    # every (refresh_rate) # of seconds

    while True:

        # Makes several http requests 
        # and passes responses through multiple functions

        # Escape infinite loop
        if screen.getch() == ord('q'):
            break

        # Wait before going through the loop again
        time.sleep(refresh_rate)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    curses.wrapper(main)
```

My other solution was to replace while True with:

```
loop = 1
while loop:

    #Loop code

if screen.getch() == ord('q'):
    loop = -1
```

This way, there is no need to press and hold 'q' to exit the program. But it can still take up to 8 seconds to exit after pressing 'q' once.

For obvious reasons, this doesn't seem to be the best way of exiting the program. I am pretty sure there should be a better (faster) solution.

Other than that, the program works fine. It's 2 files with more than 300 lines, so I am posting just the relevant parts of the code with my attempted solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have nodelay already, the usual approach is to use napms with a small (20-50 milliseconds) time, and addressing your 5-seconds goal, to run the functions after several (10-25) repetitions of the getch/napms loop.

Mixing curses and standard I/O doesn't really work well unless you take care to flush things when switching between the two.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Had to put the loop inside a separate function for this to work, since breaking from the getch/napms loop wouldn't break from the main loop, obviously. So I replaced `break` inside getch/napms loop with `return`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What's probably happening is that your `'q'` is coming in between the `getch()` and the `sleep` calls. Given that `getch()` takes a fraction of a second to execute and `sleep` locks the program for 5 seconds, it's very likely that any time you press a key you're going to wait.

The easiest way to exit any python script is to press `Ctrl-C` - it spawns a `KeyBoardInterrupt` exception that can be handled like:

```
try:
while True:
    do_something()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Granted, if this is meant to be a user-facing application, that might not be sufficient. But it's also unlikely that any production application would operate without a full event loop and a UI that would allow them to exit.

Last, if you want another way of doing what you're already doing, you can use:

```
import sys
sys.stdin.read(1)
```

To read 1 bye of user input at a time. I'd go for the `Ctrl-C` route, if I were you.

Comment: I prefer not to use `Ctrl-C` for this application. But thanks for showing how to handle `KeyBoardInterrupt`. I added it to my code just in case.